# start image loader icon when pressing a link inside PHP code

Tags: php, jquery

I was trying to use an image loader when the user pressing the link. Could not work. Any idea how to do it?

I use jquery and php:

```
<script>
    $("#startlink").click(function(){
       $(".loading").show();
    }
</script>

echo"<a href='?value=$value'    id='loading'    >Start</a>  "; 
echo" <img src='img/loader.gif' class='loading;' style='display:none;' /> ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$("#loading").click(function(){
$(".loading").show();
}
</script>

<?php
echo "<a href='?value=$value' id='loading'>Start</a>"; 
echo "<img src='img/loader.gif' class='loading' style='display:none;' />";
?>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FlameTrap/fFuPx/

Answer (score 0):

Here is your updated code, but you are going to need to use AJAX on the startlink url as it is not going to fire.

```
<script>
$("#startlink").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".loading").show();
}
</script>


echo"<a href='?value=$value' id='startlink'    >Start</a>  "; 
echo" <img src='img/loader.gif' class='loading' style='display:none;' /> ";
```